# input form to mysql with a live search bar to input a foreign key

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Update Nov 6th.

I opened the console and found this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>  http://localhost/skripsi-manual/input-pengguna.php:59 
>  [Learn More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined)

The page above suggested that I got the error because:

1. Variable is not declared
2. Wrong scope

For the first probable cause, I tried resolving it by changing lines `this` and `data` in the script to `id_jenisPembayaran`.

It didn't work. I still got **ReferenceError** message in line 59. The same happened when I changed `this` and `data` to `inputval`

As for the second probable cause, I don't think that's the problem here. Since the variable is declared within the same scope as the function.

Other solutions I've tried to solve this issue:

1. Moving the php code to insert the typed data to **livesearch-jenispengguna.php**, under `include_once`.
2. Putting the `<script>` tags above `<!Doctype html>`
3. Using `<script source ="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"> </script>` instead of `<script source= "./assets/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"> </script>`

And the efforts above still got me **ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 http://localhost/skripsi-manual/input-pengguna.php:59**

Could anyone show me what's wrong with my code?

It's quite confusing as to why the live search code works as a stand alone but results in **ReferenceError** when integrated in a form.

---

I'm creating a form to input *Pengguna* table into MySQL.

It's consisted of

```
id_pengguna (int), 
nama_pengguna (varchar), 
password, (varchar)
id_jenisPengguna (int, Foreign Key from another table called *jenispengguna).
```

The HTML Form input-pengguna.php is as following:

```html
<body>
<main>
    <div class="content">
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
        
            <article class="card">
                <h4 id="data_pengguna">Masukkan Pengguna</h4>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label for="id_pengguna">Kode Pengguna:</label>
                <input type="text" name="id_pengguna" id="id_pengguna" value ="<?php echo $id_pengguna?>">
                <br>
                <br>
                <label for="nama_pengguna">Nama Pengguna:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nama_pengguna" id="nama_pengguna" value ="<?php echo $nama_pengguna?>">
                <br>
                <br>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value ="<?php echo $password?>">
                <br>
                <br>
           <div class="livesearch">
                <label for="id_jenisPengguna">Id Jenis Pengguna:</label>
                <input type="text" autocomplete= "off">
            </div>
            <div class = "result">
            </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <button input type="submit" value="Masukkan">Masukkan</button>
            </article>
        </form>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
```

Following is the php code to insert **id_pengguna**, **nama_pengguna**, **password**, and **id_jenisPengguna** (this is inside **input-pengguna.php**)

```php
<?php
include_once './assets/php/accordion-jumbotron.php';
include_once './assets/php/connecttodb.php';
  
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$id_pengguna = ""; $nama_pengguna = "";
$password = ""; $id_jenisPengguna = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        // Assigning variables with data from input fields
        $id_pengguna = trim($_POST["id_pengguna"]);
        $nama_pengguna = trim($_POST["nama_pengguna"]);
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
        $id_jenisPengguna = trim($_POST["id_jenisPengguna"]);

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO pengguna 
                            (id_pengguna, nama_pengguna, password, id_jenispengguna) 
                    VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
            
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "issi", $param_id_pengguna, 
                                                    $param_nama_pengguna, 
                                                    $param_password, 
                                                    $param_id_jenisPengguna);
                
            // Set parameters
            $param_id_pengguna = $id_pengguna;
            $param_nama_pengguna = $nama_pengguna;
            $param_password = $password;
            $param_id_jenisPengguna = $id_jenisPengguna;
    
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: /skripsi-manual/display-pengguna.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Ada yang salah. Mohon cek coding";
            }
            
            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
        
    }
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($connect);
?>

<!Doctype HTML>
```

This is php code for searching **id_jenisPengguna** in **jenispengguna** table (livesearch-jenispengguna.php).

```php
<?php
include_once './assets/php/connecttodb.php';
 
if(isset($_REQUEST["term"])){
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM jenispengguna WHERE id_jenisPengguna LIKE ?";
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_term);
        
        // Set parameters
        $param_term = $_REQUEST["term"] . '%';
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            
            // Check number of rows in the result set
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                // Fetch result rows as an associative array
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    echo "<p>" . $row["id_jenisPengguna"] . "</p>";
                }
            } else{
                echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($connect);
        }
    }
     
    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
 
// close connection
mysqli_close($connect);
```

And this is the script to live-search the data and to store the result (inside input-pengguna.php).

```js
<script source="./assets/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.livesearch input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
                /* Get input value on change */
                var inputVal = $(id_jenisPengguna).val();
                var resultDropdown = $(id_jenisPengguna).siblings(".result");
                if(inputVal.length){
                    $.get("./assets/php/livesearch-jenispengguna.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                        // Display the returned data in browser
                        resultDropdown.html(data);
                    });
                } else{
                    resultDropdown.empty();
                }
            });
            
            // Set search input value on click of result item
            $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
                $(id_jenisPengguna).parents(".livesearch").find('input[type="text"]').val($(id_jenisPengguna).text());
                $(id_jenisPengguna).parent(".result").empty();
            });
        });
</script>
 </head>
```

As you can see, this;

```
<input type="text" name="id_pengguna" id="id_pengguna" value ="<?php echo $id_pengguna?>">
```

this;

```
<input type="text" name="nama_pengguna" id="nama_pengguna" value ="<?php echo $nama_pengguna?>">
```

and this;

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value ="<?php echo $password?>">
```

are supposed to insert (respectively) *id_pengguna*, *nama_pengguna*, and *password* into *pengguna* table

While:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete= "off">
```

is supposed to live-search *id_jenisPengguna* in **jenispengguna** table and store the result in here:

```
<div class = "result">
<br>
<br>
```

The clicked result will then be filled in `<input type ="text" autocomplete = "off">`

This way, user doesn't have to go to **display-jenispengguna.php** (this is where *jenispengguna* data is displayed) then manually type the *id_jenisPengguna* in the HTML form.

A.K.A, this form is supposed to insert the typed data and search **id_jenisPengguna** in *jenispengguna*, into *pengguna* table.

The live-search code itself is copy-edited from [here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-ajax-live-search.php). Before implementing this to **input-pengguna**, I simply copy-pasted the whole code and tested it. It worked just fine.

But, when once implemented, `<input type = "text" autocomplete = "off">` doesn't function as a live-search bar. When I type "1" (which exists in *jenispengguna* table), the result doesn't appear.

I tried browsing in google and stackoverflow, but none of the result seems to solve my problem.

Could anyone show me what's wrong with the code above and how to solve them?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Dare I suggest you read - how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `id_jenisPengguna` is according to the way you store it, not an integer? `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_term);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Yes, it's an integer. It's the id of _jenispengguna_ (type of user. for example: admin, user, manager, etc. I use this to manage access level)

Comment: But when you insert it `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isss", $param_id_pengguna, 
                                                    $param_nama_pengguna, 
                                                    $param_password, 
                                                    $param_id_jenisPengguna);` You use `s` as the datatype

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Yep. I realized that error. However, I still got **ReferenceError** after I've fixed that.